# pause slide on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a particular slide to stop as I hover the mouse on it.

The javascript code I tried :

```js
$( ".rotate-slider" ).hover(function() {
  $( this ).find( ".rotate-slider" ).stop( true, true ).fadeOut();
}, function() {
  $( this ).find( ".rotate-slider" ).stop( true, true ).fadeIn();
});
```

also I tried to use css to get it :

```css
.rotating-slide:hover .slider
{
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Unfortunately,none of the above code seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check updated code here : [jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/mqv1w538/8/](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/mqv1w538/8/)

You need to user clearInterval when hover and on hover out need to init it again

```
$( ".rotate-slider li" ).hover(function() {      
    clearInterval(rotateInterval);
}, function() {
  rotateInterval = window.setInterval(function(){
                if(!rotateSlider.slidesContainer.hasClass('animate')){
                    rotateSlider.slidesContainer.addClass('animate')
                }
                currentRotation = currentRotation - rotateSlider.slideAngle;
                rotateSlider.slidesContainer.css('transform', 'translateX(-50%) rotate('+currentRotation+'deg)');
            }, 4000);
});
```

Comment: there is an issue here.When I hover the pointer in one of the sliders,it stops.But when I take the cursor away from a slide and take the cursor below the slides,in the grey semi-circle area,it doesnot resume the rotation.Why is this happening ? any idea.thanks.

Comment: You can check updated code and fiddle. This happening because slider ul cover whole area. So when hover over it stop. So I have change it to li hover.